# Is μάλα (mala, adv.) derived or cognate with some adjective?

Tags: ancient-greek, adjective, adverb

In Attic Greek, μάλα is an adverb meaning "very, very much, exceedingly." Is it derived from some adjective, or is there an adjective that is its cognate?

- Is μακρός (makros) the adjective?
- πολύς (polus) is an adjective meaning much and many. In terms of meanings, it corresponds to μάλα (adv.). But μάλα doesn't seem to be derived from πολύς, nor do they seem to be cognates?

Comment: I'm not sure about other Greek adjectives, but Latin *multus* and *melior* seem to share a PIE origin. Obviously, μᾶλλον and μάλιστα are different degrees of the same adverb.

Answer (score 3):

There are no clear cognates in Greek, besides the comparative μᾶλλον and the superlative μάλιστα. As brianpck says, Latin *multus* and *melior* are cognate, as is Latv. *milns* "very many".

There is a rare adjective μαλερός of uncertain meaning, possibly "strong" or "violent", which has been conjectured to be cognate, but the semantic uncertainty makes this doubtful. There is no phonological way to connect either  μακρός or πολύς with μάλα.